# How to initialize the arrayList when creating a new method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am creating a program to find the sum of any two array element equal to the given value I required. When checking for appropriate patches 
ex.,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PairedSums {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> pairedOfValues(int[] a,int givenValue){
        Arrays.sort(a);

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;
        int n = a.length - 1;
        if (a[0] == givenValue){
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(a[0]);
            return arrayList;
        }
        else if (a[n] == givenValue){
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(a[0]);
            return arrayList;
        }
        else {
            int low = 0;
            int high = n;
            while (a[low] < a[high]){
                if (a[low] == givenValue){
                    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    arrayList.add(a[low]);
                    return arrayList;
                }
                else if (a[high] == givenValue){
                    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    arrayList.add(a[high]);
                    return arrayList;
                }
                else if ((low == high )){
                    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    arrayList.add(a[high]);
                    return arrayList;
                }
                if (a[low] == 0){
                    low++;
                }
                else if (a[high] == 0){
                    high--;
                }
                else {
                    int sum = a[low] + a[high];
                    if (sum == givenValue){
                        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        arrayList.add(a[low]);
                        arrayList.add(a[high]);
                        return arrayList;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (sum < givenValue){
                            low++;
                        }
                        else {
                            high--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = {10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30};
        int givenValue = 45;
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = pairedOfValues(a,givenValue);
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

I have keep initialize the array every time I am doing it and adding it manually. I have try to create a method

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> sum(ArrayList<Integer> arr,int[] a,int i){
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(a[i]);
        return arr;
    }
```

but when I declare it in the if else statement it says the ArrayList variable is not initialized which is correct. Is there any way I could initialize it in the method only so that I might not have to initialize it over and over again.

Comment: What do you return if both `if` and `else if` conditions are false?

Comment: Why would you initialize it in if block?You should initialize in common place and change it. Please post complete code and I'll try to answer in details

Comment: Also I don't see where you are adding them

Comment: the question is not clear. may be you should post the complete code.

Comment: I just added the patch not the full code.

Comment: @NuOne T Attygalle. I didn't added the full code because it was already performing as expected, my problem was just with the check ins.

Comment: @prms you can see the full code now

Comment: @user7 as can you

Comment: can you describe your problem please. i think if you intialize arraylist like this ` ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); ` problem should fix in your pairedOfValues method

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct (algorithm is not perfect, but it does not matter). I've just put you code into my IDE and got ~10 warnings and fixed all of them. When you have to create `List` with predefined amount of items, do use `Collections.singletonList()` and/or `Arrays.asList()`. Below is you code with little formatting, I think it looks much better and does not have your problem:

```
public static List<Integer> pairedOfValues(int[] a, int givenValue) {
    Arrays.sort(a);

    int n = a.length - 1;

    if (a[0] == givenValue || a[n] == givenValue)
        return Collections.singletonList(a[0]);

    int low = 0;
    int high = n;

    while (a[low] < a[high]) {
        if (a[low] == givenValue)
            return Collections.singletonList(a[low]);

        if (a[high] == givenValue || low == high)
            return Collections.singletonList(a[high]);

        if (a[low] == 0)
            low++;
        else if (a[high] == 0)
            high--;
        else {
            int sum = a[low] + a[high];

            if (sum == givenValue)
                return Arrays.asList(a[low], a[high]);

            if (sum < givenValue)
                low++;
            else
                high--;
        }
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

**P.S.** I think this you algorithm does not cover situations, when given `arr` has more than one pairs. Do look at my one, it has less code with same functionality (this is only for your further investigation).

```
public static List<Integer> pairedOfValues(int[] arr, int givenValue) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length < 2)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length && arr[i] + arr[j] <= givenValue; j++)
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == givenValue) {
                res.add(arr[i]);
                res.add(arr[j]);
            }
    }

    return res;

}
```

Comment: Is there any way you can write it with less time complexity?

Comment: @Vishal I think yes. But code will more complex. In my opinion *time complex* is not a critical point in any case. Readable (i.e. high supported) code is much more important. Therefore, I am going to work at time comple of given piece of code only if I am 100% sure that this is **the problem** for the application.

Comment: The program you added above both of them, when i check them for more than two pairs , it's showing null for the new one you added and for the older one it is an empty array. Is there something I may have been missing in main method?

Comment: It is possible, I did not check it. Debugging is your friend.